# Deleting a row from the database using php

Tags: php, mysql

how do I search a certain ID from the database? Then if it does not exist, it should show me that the id is not found and if it exists it should show me so, such as "the id has been deleted successfully".

This is my code:
This is the code that I used to delete an item, it is deleting but when I put in an ID that does not exist, nothing appears at all:

```php
<!-- THIS IS MY DATABASE CONNECTOR/I SAVED IT AS (dbconn.php) -->
<?php 
$hostname="localhost"; 
$username="root"; 
$password=""; 
$conn=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password); 
if(!conn){
  die("There is no connection to the mysql server".mysql_error()); 
} 
$mysql_db=mysql_select_db("djwriters", $conn); 
if(!$mysql_db){
  die("There is no database onnection". mysql_error());     
}
?>

<!-- THIS IS WHERE IS INPUT A TEXTBOX AND A DELETE BUTTON.
     I saved it as (tash.php) -->  
<body>
  <table width="840">
    <tr>     
      <td>
      <form action="reason.php" method="post" name="frmreason">     
        <label>ID:</label><input name="ID" type="text" />     
        <input type="submit" name="delete" id="Delete" value="Delete" />     
      </form>
      </td>   
    </tr>
  </table>    
</body> 

<!-- THIS IS NOW THE CODE THAT I USED TO DELETE THE ROW.
     I saved it as (delete.php) -->
<?php 
include("dbconn.php"); 
if(isset($_POST['delete'])and $_POST['ID']){ 
  $sql="DELETE FROM `djwriters`.`personal` WHERE `personal`.`ID` ='$_POST[ID]'";
  mysql_query($sql) or die("The id was not found".mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Would someone help me? The code should search an item from the database when you click the delete button and if it `enter code here` is not there, it should show me or display an error and if there it `enter code here` should tell me deleted successfully. use `isset` function in PHP

Comment: You need to issue a `select` on the ID and check the return value of that prior to deleting it. Delete itself is silent.

Comment: Hi. I've tidied up your question a bit. It would be helpful if, in future, you checked the formatting in the edit preview before you saved the question. You can still improve this question by clicking "edit" if you wish.

Comment: mysql_affected_rows() after the Delete query will tell you how many rows were deleted... 1 if a row existed, 0 if it didn't.... but you should be using MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements to avoid the risk of SQL injection rather than the deprecated MySQL extension

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to get a row by its ID, use **SELECT**:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

```
SELECT `field`, `field2`, `...` FROM `my_table` WHERE id = $id
```

If you'd like to delete a row by its ID, use **DELETE**:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html

```
DELETE FROM `my_table` WHERE id = $id
```

To check, how many rows were affected, use the PHP-function **mysql_affected_rows()**:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

**Offtopic**:
I recommend using PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

That should help you. :-)